# creating a shell script to modify and/or create bookmarks in firefox

Tags: sql, bash, sqlite, shell, firefox

I have several applications that change IP addresses every-time they are deployed.

I am wondering how I can create a bash shell script to:

1. Modify/update existing Firefox bookmarks
2. If the bookmarks don't exist, then create them.

After some research, I found that I need to modify `places.sqlite`, so I downloaded `sqlite`. I looked at the [schema](http://people.mozilla.org/~dietrich/places-erd.png), and I think moz_places and moz_bookmarks are what I need to insert to, but I am not sure. If so, how would connect the ids if I need to 2 separate inserts. I already have a way to get the new ip address for every new deployment, so I would just stick that into a variable.

My use case looks something like this:

```
Deployment 1: URL: 192.168.1.**10**/app1
Deployment 2: URL: 192.168.1.**20**/app1
```

Brownie points if I can create multiple folders 1st and insert bookmarks inside them. Like {Folder#1: app1, app2}, {Folder#2: app3}, {Folder#3: app4, app5, app6}.

Comment: A much more sane approach would be to set up internal DNS and just update the IP address there, then bookmark by hostname once and for all.

Comment: Are you looking for instructions for how to set up a DNS server?  Google it.  If you need help, you'll need to provide a lot more details about your server-side environment and also go to a different site, as this is not a programming question (I would suggest https://serverfault.com/ but look for existing questions before you post another one).

Comment: I will say this just once more: abandon your approach and create a bookmark to http://service.intra/app1 and then centrally change which IP address `service.intra` resolves to from your DNS server. This is one of the reasons we have DNS.

Comment: For a single box, DNS is not needed, just update the /etc/hosts file with the IP and the name you want to use in the URL.

Comment: Another really simple (workaround) solution would be to bookmark a local file and then periodically update that file to have a meta refresh that goes to your true target.

Comment: Three very fine workarounds above. But if you *really* want to mess with FireFox bookmarks, you will need to carefully perform some SQLite DML https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data

Answer (score 0):

A shell script might not be the best tool for this problem; but you could use a script like this to redirect your browser to a new location each time your application redeploys, and bookmark `localhost:<port>`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# redirect localhost:<port> to another address with HTML                                                                

local_port="${1:?provide local port to listen on}"                                                                 
redirect="${2:?provide application ip address}"                                                      

while :; do                                                                     
  (                                                                             
    echo "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"                                                      
    echo ""                                                                     
    echo "<head>"
    echo "  <meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=$redirect\" />"
    echo "</head>"
    echo ""                                                                     
  ) | ncat -l -p "$local_port" > /dev/null                                               

done
```

This would let you bookmark `localhost:8000` in Firefox, and call the script when you redeploy. You could have an instance of the script running for each app; you'd just need to change the listening port. If you have a script that redeploys your app, you could add these lines there.

```
$ bash redirect.sh 8000 192.168.1.10/app1
$ bash redirect.sh 8001 192.168.1.11/app1
```